# expressionengine stopped parsing some tags after adding some content

Tags: php, expressionengine

i am modifying an expression engine channel entry, there are a number of fields for this channel in a group and two are grids. in the template, i have loops that go through the rows in the grid and output various fields. this is all working as expected.

i recently wanted to add some content, and when i did my existing loops were no longer parsed, just output

```
{grid_name0}
    <div>stuff</div>
{/grid_name0}
```

and any `{grid_name0:fieldname}` were replaced with empty string/nothing. other tags continued to work correctly, including tags and a loop in the new content i added.

after debugging a bit, i discovered that there is a specific amount of text that will break it, i can add a comment to the template like
    `<!-- 01234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789 -->`
that when i get to a certain length it will break the page. this seems like maybe a memory limit is being reached before expression engine processes all the content, i checked various areas for memory limits and they seem to be set at reasonable values (and this is a pretty simple/light site), however i suspect there is a limit set somewhere that i am not aware of.

this is on expression engine 2.7.2 with php 5.2.17, i can provide additional details from phpinfo if desired but the php memory_limit is set to 512M (which, frankly, seems like way overkill).

possibly related, but one of the things i was adding is an "advanced" condition with an `{if:else}`, if i have this present but less text than is required to break the page it will also break in the exact same way.

thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: If you turn on template debugging it gives you detail on memory usage. Can you update your post to detail anything extra-ordinary you see there?

Comment: i will try that, this only occurs on production (of course :(...) and not on my dev setup. that is probably an important detail to add as well, i have the exact database and code as production and it works for my local setup using php 5.5.13.

Comment: @AllInOne - nothing unexpected in the template debugging, identical output between working/broken with a bit of additional multi_language output for some translations. memory use goes down slightly which makes sense as those tags are not processing correctly.

Comment: i was able to add one of my advanced conditionals in by removing some other comment, but if i add the second conditional it breaks. just feels like expression engine gets tired and refuses to parse any more content at some point in the template processing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

huge thanks to ellis labs support, they pointed me to increasing the pcre.backtrack_limit beyond the default 100000 and it now processes all the tags. in retrospect i should have checked that sooner, but run into issues with it so infrequently it never crossed my mind.

edit *system/expressionengine/config/config.php* and add this just after the initial line:

```
ini_set('pcre.backtrack_limit', 100000000);
```